# Delete a BitBucket Head

Tags: bitbucket, sourcetree

I currently have a BitBucket repository and it has two heads on the same default branch. The head *58fb256* is very outdated, while the *3c9d5a3* branch is the newest. I am trying to find out a way to delete the *58fb256* head from my repository.

[image]

Comment: How did you create the multiple HEADs?  Was it the [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) command?

Comment: Are you working with Git or Mercurial? (Bitbucket supports both.)

Comment: Yes, this is a Mercurial repository. And I created the multiple heads by using the SouceTree console.